# Flutter App unfortunately stops working with Unable to start activity ComponentInfo error

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have created a flutter application that works well on a physical phone but when I try it out on an emulator the application stops unfortunately. Error produced `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{big.xxxx.xxxxx/xxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/launch_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f040019`

**I have checked and the launch_background.xml is present. Here is the content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <!-- <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item> -->
</layer-list>
```

Comment: make sure the `launch_background.xml` is present in you android project

Comment: I have checked and the launch_background.xml is present. I have edited my question with the content of the xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking around I was able to solve the problem by removing the instances where I call the drawable file.
This was mainly in my styles.xml file and Manifest.xml file respectively.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>

<meta-data  android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"        android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
```

Had an opportunity of asking another person who had solved this problem differently and this is what he had to say.

**The underlying cause**

The underlying cause seems to be that the  expects a bitmap but it didn't get one. Even though @mipmap/ic_launcher points to some PNGs (see e.g. res/mipmap-hdpi), on API >= 26, it would point to this XML which Android did not seem to like very much.

So in my case, referencing the @drawable (which is always a PNG == a nice bitmap) rather than the @mipmap (which may be an adaptive-icon == a weird bitmap? if a bitmap at all?) fixed it.

In other words: don't use an  as the android:src of a .

If I'd to this today I would try if a vector drawable (just import an SVG in Android Studio to get the vector XML) works as well (as opposed to having to use a PNG).

Hope that helps (or at least explains this change of mine).

Do double check that you have the same issue - Resources$NotFoundException may be thrown for many different reasons, e.g. the ressource being in the drawable-v26 folder and thus ignored when running on e.g. API 24. Sometimes the gradle build log shows some warning saying that an XML failed to compile (but the build still succeeds and then things blow up at runtime).

Best search the internet for other causes and fixes for Resources$NotFoundException if it's not the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have deleted your launch_background.xml this is the first screen that is execute in your Android when you are using Flutter. Check in the path /android/app/src/main/drawable if you have the launch_background.xml.
If you don't you must added in your project.

Comment: I have checked and the launch_background.xml is present. or should I delete and add it again?

Comment: You should check if in your AndroidManifest.xml if it's using the launch_background.
You should have something like this:
<meta-data
     android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
     android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
There is 3 AndroidManifest check if you have in the 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment this out in **android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>
```

Comment: This is **exactly** what this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001139/12695027) by [Sefu Zephaniah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6527581/sefu-zephaniah) says to do. Only they also added an explanation.